# Replace VBA's object "Empty" with pythoncom.Missing doesn't work

Tags: python, win32com, solidworks

Few years ago I wrote script in Python to automate few tedious processes that I was doing in SolidWorks_2012. I was running that script on Win7 32 bit with python 27 32 bit and SolidWorks_2012 32 bit.

Now, I faced exactly the same problem and I tried to use old script but on **OpenDoc6** (and on others functions, where **values pass by ref**) it raises exception:

```
"Objects of type 'PyOleMissing' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT"
```

Here is some sample that I can't make to work:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pythoncom

sw = win32.Dispatch('SldWorks.Application')
path_to_file = "some_path"
sw_asm = sw.OpenDoc6(path_to_file, 2, 1, "", pythoncom.Missing, pythoncom.Missing)
```

Here is some specification of this function from docs for VBA:

```
Function OpenDoc6( _
   ByVal FileName As System.String, _
   ByVal Type As System.Integer, _
   ByVal Options As System.Integer, _
   ByVal Configuration As System.String, _
   ByRef Errors As System.Integer, _
   ByRef Warnings As System.Integer _
) As ModelDoc2
```

As you can see two latest are passing by references.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454804/pointer-callout-for-selectbyid2) is the same issue without any solution.
And just in case this may be important, now I'm running win 8 64,  python 27 32/64 and SolidWorks 2014 64.

Comment: Try using ``pythoncom.Empty`` instead, which will provide a ``VT_EMPTY`` param (rather than ``pythoncom.Missing``, which provides nothing at all)

Comment: I did what you suggested but it raises another error. And just to be clear, I've tried all COM Variants, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

just insert empty variables. Had the same error in VBA where you had to pass variables declared as LONG or it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is what worked for me:

```
Ierror = win32.VARIANT( pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_I4 , 0)
Iwarning = win32.VARIANT( pythoncom.VT_BYREF | pythoncom.VT_I4, 0)

swModel = sldworks.OpenDoc6(fname, swDocDRAWING, swOpenDocOptions_Silent,"", Ierror, Iwarning)
```